# How to make calculation by taking data from other tables' columns and inserting it into another table's data column?

Tags: mysql

I have these tables in my database:

- `employee` (`emp_id`, `emp_name`, `dept_id`, `type_of_work`, `hourly_rate`)
- `department` (`dept_id`, `dept_name`, `dept_location`)
- `address` (`emp_id,street_no`, `street_name`, `city`, `zip_code`)
- `project` (`project_id`, `project_name`, `project_location`)
- `ft_pt_work` (project_id`,`emp_id, dept_id`,`num_of_hours`,`works_date`)
- `salary` (`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary, salary_date`)

Here:

- `type_of_work` defines the type of employment (e.g. full time/part time, input should be 'F/P')
- `net_salary` = basic + ( (1.0) + (0.45) + (-0.09) + (-0.15))

For the part-time employee, `basic = hourly_rate * num_of_hours`

For calculating the net_salary from basic, I have made this trigger and it yielded net_salary of **full-time employees** in the salary table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER salary_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON salary
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SET NEW.net_salary := NEW.basic * ( (1.0) + (0.45) + (-0.09) + (-0.15) );
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

After that, I made this second trigger below for calculating the basic and then net_salary of **part-time employees**, but am getting the basic and net_salary column NULL! How can I make this correct?

My Code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER basic_pt_employees
BEFORE INSERT ON salary
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee,ft_pt_work WHERE employee.type_of_work='P' AND employee.emp_id=NEW.emp_id) > 0 THEN
        SET NEW.basic := employee.hourly_rate * ft_pt_work.num_of_hours;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: totals/counts or better says calculations depending on "running" data should not really be stored, this conflicts with normalization "rules" instead you need to aggregate the results on the fly when you need them.. Also because triggers can be "hard" to debug because of non existing stacktraces/logging

Comment: The result would be NULL because `SET NEW.basic := employee.hourly_rate * ft_pt_work.num_of_hours` is plain wrong. You need to *SELECT* them from their respective tables using `NEW.emp_id` instead.